# External image details getting added in order email template in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, product-images, email-templates, order-email

I am trying to add product image in the sales order email template with overriding in the path

> /app/design/frontend/vendor/Mytheme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml.

Code Written:

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
    $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    $image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->setImageFile($_product->getFile())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();?>
<img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>"/>
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this in the mail. originals source is overridden by src which is getting generated. Not able to get an image in the mail.

**Inspected element:**

```
<img data-imagetype="External" **src="/actions/ei?u=http%3A%2F%2F...%3A1080%2FQPwebstore%2Fpub%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fb%2Fa%2Fballpen_with_stylus1.jpg&amp;d=2019-04-16T13%3A15%3A46.063Z"** 
 **originalsrc="http://......./pub/media/catalog/product/b/a/ballpen_with_stylus1.jpg"** data-connectorsauthtoken="1" data-imageproxyendpoint="/actions/ei" data-imageproxyid="" class="x_product-image-photo" width="200" height="200" alt="Stylus Pen" style="border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none">
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue..

Comment: <img data-imagetype="External" **src="/actions/ei?u=http%3A%2F%2F...%3A1080%2FQPwebstore%2Fpub%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fb%2Fa%2Fballpen_with_stylus1.jpg&amp;d=2019-04-16T13%3A15%3A46.063Z"** 
 **originalsrc="http://......./pub/media/catalog/product/b/a/ballpen_with_stylus1.jpg"** data-connectorsauthtoken="1" data-imageproxyendpoint="/actions/ei" data-imageproxyid="" class="x_product-image-photo" width="200" height="200" alt="Stylus Pen" style="border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none"> ..........this is the element while inspecting

Answer (score 0):

copy `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml` to yout template folder `app/design/frontend/[VENDOR]/[TEMPLATE]/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml` and adding the image column there...

```
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_order = $_item->getOrder();
$_store = $_order->getStore();


$_imageHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$_baseImageUrl = $_store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product';
```

and right below

```
<img src="<?= $_imageHelper->init($_item->getProduct(), 'small_image', ['type'=>'small_image'])->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('65','65')->getUrl();?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>">
```

Comment: i have tried .. i am getting same issue

Comment: any error generate ?

Comment: no error........... i am getting below one while inspecting in mail.........<img data-imagetype="External" src="/actions/ei?u=http%3A%2F%2F...%3A1080%2FQPwebstore%2Fpub%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fb%2Fa%2Fballpen_with_stylus1.jpg&amp;d=2019-04-16T13%3A15%3A46.063Z" originalsrc="http://......./pub/media/catalog/product/b/a/ballpen_with_stylus1.jpg" data-connectorsauthtoken="1" data-imageproxyendpoint="/actions/ei" data-imageproxyid="" class="x_product-image-photo" width="200" height="200" alt="Stylus Pen" style="border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none">